# Trying to override phtml template

Tags: magento-1.9, template, overrides, xml, phtml

I'm fairly new in **Magento** and trying to override a `phtml` file which is originally in

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml
```

with custom one that I ve created in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/Pawel/productsub/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml
```

In my `app/code/local/Pawel/Productsub/etc/config.xml`
I ve put this:

```
<config>
...
       <frontend>
            <layout version="0.1.0">
                <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
                    <reference name="product.info">
                        <action method="setTemplate">
                            <template>catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                    </reference>
                </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    ...
    </config>
```

And this is the layout i'm trying to change `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml`

```
 <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me out and explain a little what I'm doing wrong, it gets me a little nervous already.

Answer (score 1):

You have added wrong code in your `config.xml`, you have to add below code there-

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
           <module_name>
              <file>your_layout_file_name.xml</file>
           </module_name>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then create `your_layout_file_name.xml` under your theme's layout directory and add below code there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
        <reference name="product_type_data">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>pawel/productsub/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
</layout>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answering
i did all you said , i changed the config.xml code and "linked" pawel_productsub.xml, 
created xml file under app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/pawel_productsub.xml
moved my template from pawel/produtsub to pawel_productsub
deleted cache, but nothing really changed, its still using the base layout

Comment: most welcome, let me know if you face any issue :)

Comment: please put these files in your current theme directory as well and check if your Module is enable from admin System -> Configuration -> Advanced

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't update the base files `app/design/frontend/base/default`, you create the same path in your current theme then Magento load the file from the current theme according to the **theme fallback system**.
2. Put your layout update in `local.xml` the exact path: `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/layout/local.xml` and not in `config.xml`