# Magento 1 - How to override phtml file in module?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, sales-order

I am using magento 1
I am trying to override the below phtml file in module

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml
```

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please prefer following link to fulfil your issue.

[Override phtml file in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195509/91911)

If this answer helps you then hit like.

Thank you,
Hiren Patel

Comment: Thankyou, i will check it.

Comment: Not working for me